# ListView.builder is not overlapping in Stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have been using `ListView.builder` in `Stack`. But the rounded containers are not overlapping each other. How can I overlap them? I have attached the code and screenshot of output as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Emniii extends StatelessWidget {
  const Emniii({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 30,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 13,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Current Output**

[image]

**what I am expecting**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) is the most commonly used scrolling widget. It displays its children one after another in the scroll direction. In the cross axis, the children are required to fill the ListView.

In your case you just want to generate `13` `Container`s, use loop or `List.generate` and use `Positioned` widget to align them.

I am using `left: index * 15,` it is shifting right by container's half width.

```dart
child: Stack(
  children: [
    ...List.generate(
      13,
      (index) => Positioned(
        left: index * 15,
        child: Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: index.isEven ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

More about [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) and [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: I have update a photo that I am expecting actually. Can you check it please?

Comment: Updated,  you can find more about [Positioned widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)